# how do you get a reference to the directive object instance in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jstree

So basically I have a directive which wraps a jquery plugin (jsTree if that matters). All i want is just a way to get the directive object so that I can use the exposed plugin object and do some modifications without really building a func into my directive.

```js
var ngJSTree = angular.module('jsTree.directive', []);
ngJSTree.directive('jsTree', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    var treeDir = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      fetchResource: function(url, cb) {
        return $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
          if (cb) cb(data.data);
        });
      },
      .
      .
      .
      init: function(s, e, a, config) {
        treeDir.managePlugins(s, e, a, config);
        this.tree = $(e).jstree(config);
        treeDir.manageEvents(s, e, a);
      }
    };

    return treeDir;
  }
]);
```

I could very well just implement a registry mechanism of my own and add it to map for each directive , but is there a simpler way like possibly giving an id and accessing it . Something like how dojo had `dijit.byId` or like how jquery plugins give you access through the dom (Weird but works !!!) .

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done by design.  You shouldn't be trying to get the directive object directly.

Instead, require the directive and access its controller in the link function (this is one way that directives communicate).

For example:

```
<div directive1>
      <div directive2>
      </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
app.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function firstCtrl($scope) {
            ...
        }
    }
});

app.directive('directive2', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^directive1',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, firstCtrl) {
            ... use firstCtrl ...
        }
    }
});
```